# Scrapy : ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to learn scrapy for a project. I receive this error ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression but I don't understand what is wrong in my script.

It's my script

```
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'user_agent': str(response.request.headers['User-Agent']),
            'links' : response.xpath('//a[@class="sc-996f251d-0 leAMGT"]/@href').getall()
        }



        next = response.xpath('//a[@title="Page suivante"]/')
        print(next)
```

Here is a piece of the scraped page:

```
        <a class="indexstyles__PaginateItem-sc-8rtl5h-3 YJHOY" title="Page suivante"  href="/locations_saisonnieres/offres/p-2">
```

It's the error:

```
      ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in //a[@title="Page  suivante"]/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is an extra **'/'** in your Xpath that's why it's showing an error!
so instead of `//a[@title="Page suivante"]/` use `//a[@title="Page suivante"]` and That should work!

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'user_agent': str(response.request.headers['User-Agent']),
        'links' : response.xpath('//a[@class="sc-996f251d-0 leAMGT"]/@href').getall()
    }



    next = response.xpath('//a[@title="Page suivante"]/')
    print(next)
```